# Questions about setting up PHP-ODBC driver for remote SQL-Server-2008 connection on CentOS-6

Tags: sql-server-2008, odbc, centos-6, php5

I have CentOS 6 and PHP 5.3.3 VPS at [GoDaddy](http://GoDaddy.com). I have to interact with remote SQL Server 2008. I've seen many tutorials and quite lost here, so:

1. There is a way to simply `yum install` it ?
2. If not, what are my options ? just [FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org/) ?

If [FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org/) is my only way, then:

1. What are the command line input variables for the `./configure` command ?
2. After `make` and `make install`, do I still have to copy the `*.so` file(s?) somewhere ?
3. Do I need to point `php.ini` to the extension like `extension=/somewhere/whatever-odbc-file.so` ?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the steps in this guide: http://www.savelono.com/linux/how-to-configure-linux-odbc-connections-for-ms-sql.html

Answer (score 0):

FreeTDS is not your only option.  There are drivers from other sources, including [my employer's offering](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-sqlserver-st/).

You may benefit from reading over [this guide to using ODBC with PHP](http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/iodbc/wiki/iODBC/IODBCPHPHOWTO) on the [iODBC.org](http://iODBC.org/) site (an open source project maintained and supported by my employer).